# How to modifiy / edit built-in Azure DevOps widgets?

Tags: widget, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I don't know how to find code of widgets provided by Microsoft in Azure DevOps so I can edit, merge and play with them.

Already checked the documentation and google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they are open-source.  I couldn't find them on github, which is where they would be if they were.  That being said, there are quite a few marketplace extension that I do know are hosted on Github.  Find one that has support page linking to github that interests you.

If you haven't already, look through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azdevops) for adding a dashboard widget.